# How do I address an object value in a whose clause in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to test a object property of elements in a whose clause.

For example, let's use the common elements "document" and "window" that almost every Mac app has:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    get document 1 --> document "Untitled"
    get window 1 --> window id 40640
    get document of window 1 --> document "Untitled"
end tell
```

So we see that window 1 has a document property that points back to a document element.

Now I like to find all documents that are in window 1 (please don't question the sense of this - while it makes little sense in this particular case, I need the solution for a different case where it's actually useful). I try this:

```
set theDoc to document of window 1 --> document "Untitled"
get every window whose document is theDoc
```

But that fails with the error ***Can’t make document into type reference. number -1700 from document to reference***.

How do I solve this without resolving to a loop command (repeat), but staying with the `whose` clause?

Comment: Have you tried using Accessibility Inspector to see the hierarchical relationship of the various objects all well as the information it exposes?  I find that this can be very helpful in the formulation of a statement.

Comment: I am using Script Debugger's Explorer, which is superb for this job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `its` or `of it`, like this:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set theDoc to document of window 1
    get every window whose its document is theDoc
    -- or --> get every window whose document of it is theDoc
end tell
```